# How to map specific HTML table columns and get its data into an array (JS)?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

I'm trying to get the table data from some columns and I've tried a couple of variations I could think of, but none worked:

```
function updateAllTasks() {
var table = document.getElementById("dtable");

var [, ...tr] = table.querySelectorAll("tr");
var tableData = [...tr].map(r => {
var td = r.querySelectorAll("td");
    console.log([...td].map(c => c[0].innerHTML, c[1].innerHTML, c[8].querySelectorAll('input[name="rowcheckbox"]')[0].value)); //This is the one giving me error ReferenceError: c is not defined
})
console.log(JSON.stringify(tableData));
}
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Would it be easier to have the data in an array and then build the table?

Comment: ...like get everything first and map it afterwards, @Andy?

Comment: Sure. But it depends where the data is coming from. I tend to think "data => build something with the data" rather than the other way round. But that's just one opinion.

Comment: I thought that handling the specific columns' data would be optimal = one step less, but your suggestion worked. Thanks, @Andy!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned by [Andy](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1377002/andy), following data structures logic. The best approach for this case will be to call the data inside of an [Array](https://spreadsheet.dev/arrays-apps-script), and after that, build the table with the data.

This will provide more flexibility the moment you process the information.

**Reference**

- [Javascript Array](https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/data-structures-in-javascript-with-examples/#arrays)
- [Arrays in Apps Script](https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/data-structures-in-javascript-with-examples/)